# RegEx for non-latin characters in .htaccess not working

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to add a Rewrite rule to my WordPress site's .htaccess file in order to return a 410 (Gone) for any URL (query string) that contains non-latin characters, like this one:

```
https://www.somesite.com/?s=Bob자
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# My code
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^[\x00-\x7F]*$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It works when I test it with https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

Once I add it to my .htaccess, it doesn't work anymore.

If I only add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```

I get a 410 (Gone) if I leave ?s= in the URL (proof that my .htaccess is being read and works).

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: "any URL that contains non-latin characters" - is that anywhere in the URL, including the URL-path? Your example is only checking against the query string?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "query string". I've added this in the question.